# Undefined Variable by running a script on PHP 5.4 and IIS 8

Tags: php, curl

I have a small question about running a script on windows ( IIS 8 + PHP 5.4 )
I try to make the script below to work.

```
<?php

class RadInfo {

    private $db;
    private $cfg;
    private $dnas_data;

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = Com_DB::getInstance();
        $this->cfg = new Config();
    }

    function openstats() {

        $ch = curl_init($this->cfg->shoutcasthost . '/admin.cgi?sid=' . $this->cfg->shoutcastsid . '&mode=viewxml');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $this->cfg->shoutcastport);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->cfg->shoutcastuagent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->cfg->shoutcastuser . ':' . $this->cfg->shoutcastpasswd);

        $curl = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if ($curl) {
            $xml = @simplexml_load_string($curl);
            $dnas_data = array (
                'CURRENTLISTENERS'    => $xml->CURRENTLISTENERS,
                'PEAKLISTENERS'        => $xml->PEAKLISTENERS,
                'MAXLISTENERS'        => $xml->MAXLISTENERS,
                'REPORTEDLISTENERS'    => $xml->REPORTEDLISTENERS,
                'AVERAGETIME'        => $xml->AVERAGETIME,
                'SERVERGENRE'        => $xml->SERVERGENRE,
                'SERVERURL'            => $xml->SERVERURL,
                'SERVERTITLE'        => $xml->SERVERTITLE,
                'SONGTITLE'            => $xml->SONGTITLE,
                'NEXTTITLE'            => $xml->NEXTTITLE,
                'SONGURL'            => $xml->SONGURL,
                'IRC'                => $xml->IRC,
                'ICQ'                => $xml->ICQ,
                'AIM'                => $xml->AIM,
                'STREAMHITS'        => $xml->STREAMHITS,
                'STREAMSTATUS'        => $xml->STREAMSTATUS,
                'BITRATE'            => $xml->BITRATE,
                'CONTENT'            => $xml->CONTENT,
                'VERSION'            => $xml->VERSION,
            );

            if ($dnas_data['STREAMSTATUS'] == 1)
            {
                foreach ($xml->LISTENERS->LISTENER as $listener)
                {
                    $sc_data['LISTENERS'][] = array(
                        'HOSTNAME' =>  $listener->HOSTNAME,
                        'USERAGENT' =>  $listener->USERAGENT,
                        'CONNECTTIME' =>  $listener->CONNECTTIME,
                        'POINTER' =>  $listener->POINTER,
                        'UID' =>  $listener->UID,
                    );
                }

                foreach ($xml->SONGHISTORY->SONG as $song)
                {
                    $sc_data['SONGHISTORY'][] = array(
                        'PLAYEDAT' =>  $song->PLAYEDAT,
                        'TITLE' =>  $song->TITLE,
                    );
                }
            }
        } else {
            $dnas_data = array('ERROR' => 'Could not connect to dnas-server!');
        }


    }


    function LoadServerTitle() {
            return $this->dnas_data['STREAMTITLE'];
    }


}

?>
```

I have made changes to the script but the output stays on this moment NULL.

I have tried to call the class/function thought:

```
$comcms->slim->get('/streamtitle', function() use($comcms) {
        $comcms->jsonOutput($comcms->radinfo->LoadServerTitle());
});
```

and

```
$comcms->slim->get('/streamtitle', function() use($comcms) {
    if ($comcms->radinfo->openstats()) {
        $comcms->jsonOutput($comcms->radinfo->LoadServerTitle());
    }
});
```

I have tried several options but noting work. I had first problems with cURL but that is solved because PHP fail to load the module.

Now i have problems getting any information. The LoadServerTitle gives a output that says NULL but i cant get it to work properly. 
The $this->cfg part comes out the database.

Can someone give me a idea to get this script working.
I want to thank the people that help me so far.

Comment: Show are not showing how you are acutally using this class. it seems to me that you would need to make a call to `openstats()` first and also have `openstats()` set its value to `$this->dnas_data`. Neither of these things are happening in the code example you show.

Comment: i have edit the script with the code that i use for calling it

Answer (score 1):

You declare `$dnas_data` in a method, so it won't be accessible outside that method.

I would suggest you to declare another member variable for storing the data:

```
class RadInfo {

    private $db;
    private $cfg;

    private $dnas_data;
```

And replace every occurrence of `$dnas_data` by `$this->dnas_data`

---

I just looked again at your `GetServerTitle()` method:

```
return($this->openstats($dnas_data['SERVERTITLE']));
```

Do you really want to call `openstats()` again?
Change this to :

```
return $this->dnas_data['SERVERTITLE'];
```

Comment: The changes are working only now the answer is null.

So the input is not correct and i go try to fix that

Comment: It looks like i miss something because the output stays null.
I have changed the curl options ( made changes to $this->cfg and replace that with the information in de DB )

but still the output is null

Have someone a idea what i do wrong?

Comment: @PatrickJ Try `var_dump($this->dnas_data);` in the *GetServerTitle()* method. Post the output, please, or verify that the key `SERVERTITLE` exists.

Comment: The output what i get is
NULL
null

It looks like the openstats is not triggered but i cannot get anything out it.

Comment: @PatrickJ You don't call `openstats()` before calling `GetServerTitle()`, do you? That's the problem.

Comment: What can do though is to check whether `openstats()` has already been called. If not, then `GetServerTitle()` should call it before it accesses *$this->dnas_data*. However, I would rename it to `LoadServerTitle()` then.

Comment: i cant get it to work it still says NULL and i have tried to include the function openstats did someone have an idea ?

Comment: @PatrickJ And how do you use your class? Your code only defines it, nothing will happen upon execution.

Comment: @PatrickJ Ok, i found two possible flaws: a) You aren't using `$this->dnas_data` in your method thus the member variable `$dnas_data` won't ever be set. b) You return nothing from your function thus your IF condition fails when calling. Try this code: http://pastebin.com/AbyuWcxp (if it doesn't work, post the output of *var_dump()*, please)

Comment: var_dump gives an error ( that the function not exist. )
It seems like the curl don't work. because there is no returning of any information.

Comment: @PatrickJ Are you really sure that the error message says that *var_dump* does not exist? This would be very strange! Can you post the complete error message, please?

Comment: Type: ErrorException
Code: 2
Message: var_dump() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given

arning: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: var_dump'

Comment: @PatrickJ Please fix the code according to the error message. It should really be self-explanatory.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. i go try to change the script :)